# How can I play more than one song at a time in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I've got it working now but with the time delay is there a better way because I want two different scripts to be working I want to have these playing in this order and have my images come up in order and the images are a long script and have time delays on them too.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.init()
print "hey I finaly got this working!"
sounda= pygame.mixer.Sound('D:/Users/John/Music/Music/FUN.OGG')
soundb= pygame.mixer.Sound('D:/Users/John/Music/Music/Still Alive.OGG')
soundc= pygame.mixer.Sound('D:/Users/John/Music/Music/turret.OGG')
soundd= pygame.mixer.Sound('D:/Users/John/Music/Music/portalend.OGG')
sounda.play()
pygame.time.delay(11000)
soundb.play()<P>
pygame.time.delay(180000)
soundc.play()
pygame.time.delay(90000)
soundd.play()
```

Answer (score 6):

Did you check the [pygame.Mixer](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) module ? On default, you can play 8 songs simultaneously

If you use the [pygame.mixer.music](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html), you'll be able to play only one song at the time.

If you use the [pygame.mixer.sound](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound), you'll be able to play up to 8 songs at the time.

The [music module](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) is here to stream music (it doesn't load all the music file at once).

The [sound module](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) is here to play differents sounds during game (sounds are completely loaded in memory).

So, in your example if you want to play the 4 songs at the same time :

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.init()
print "hey I finaly got this working!"
sounds = []
sounds.append(pygame.mixer.Sound('D:/Users/John/Music/Music/FUN.OGG'))
sounds.append(pygame.mixer.Sound('D:/Users/John/Music/Music/Still Alive.OGG'))
sounds.append(pygame.mixer.Sound('D:/Users/John/Music/Music/turret.OGG'))
sounds.append(pygame.mixer.Sound('D:/Users/John/Music/Music/portalend.OGG'))
for sound in sounds:
    sound.play()
```

Comment: yeah but how is it I use Channels I tryed it but how to I assign a channel a song?

Answer (score 0):

The following script will load 4 sounds (sound_0.wav to sound_3.wav) and play them.

```
sounds = []
for i in range(4):
    sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound_%d.wav'%i)
    sound.play()
    sounds.append(sound)
```