# Running multiple commands simultaneously in python

Tags: multithreading, audio, python-3.4

I'm making an application that plays multiple notes simultaneously.
I've tried multithreading and a lot of other libraries, but they all just play the sounds after oneanother.
This is what i've currently got:

```
import threading
import winsound
def playsound(notes, length):
    for note in notes:
        t = threading.Thread(target=winsound.Beep, args=(note,length))
        t.start()
playsound([100,200,300],200)
```

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535510/playing-a-lot-of-sounds-at-once

Comment: well this would work if i wanted to play audio from sound files, but i want to use winsound to play the audio.